# How do I parse [-1 1]

Tags: python-2.7, parsing, pyparsing

I am trying to parse a range which consists of bracketed, possibly signed integers, where the integers are separated by one or more spaces.  An example would be [-1 1].

My most recent attempt involved parsing the right half of this expression.  Here's my attempt:

```
import pyparsing as pp

sign=pp.oneOf('- +')
rr=pp.Optional(sign)+pp.OneOrMore(pp.nums)+pp.Literal(r']')
line=pp.Optional(rr)

test=[
    r'124',
    r'-456',
    r'+75',
    r'[-1 1] ',
    r'[1]']

for t in test:
    print t,' -> ',line.parseString(t)
```

To my way of thinking, this should have matched the fourth string in my test data.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Your grammar doesn't have an optional `[` at the beginning.

Comment: Why do I need a [ to parse [-1  1] correctly?  Shouldn't my grammar match the 1]?

Comment: Is this an exercise? If not, you can just do `[int(i) for i in line.lstrip(" [").rstrip(" ]").split()]` or similar, right?

Comment: It's part of a larger grammar.

Comment: `parseString` starts matching at the beginning of the input string - do you maybe want to use `searchString` instead?